# Simple probability problem I have 6 socks, what the average number of socks i needs to pick up to match first sock that i have in my hand.

Tags: probability

I don`t understand how it works, i mean, why we need  to do this (6+2)/2=4 and why 4 is average number of socks that we need pick up to find our pair. In my mind it could be anything from 1 to 5
What formula people use to answer and why?

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb, but now i understand why it is 4, if we need to decide what average number of socks we need to pick up before we find pair if we have 3 pairs or 6 socks is 4 because it can be  2 socks or 6 , but maximum number of socks is 6 so we need check 5 socks and with other that we have in our hands to compare 6 socks if we unlucky, if we lucky it will be only 2 with other that we have in our hands, so (6+2)/2, by averige we have 4 number of socks.

Comment: Why isn't it $(5+1)/2$? The most it could be is $5$, as there are only $5$ socks left in the drawer; the least is $5$, as the very first sock could match the one in your hand.

Comment: i don`t know in "brilliant"  they give me the answer i gave (6+2)/2, i don`t understand it fully thats why i post it here.